# How to serve html files from multiple folders inside wwwroot in .net

Tags: c#, .net, fileserver, wwwroot

I have multiple folders in wwwroot and each folder has a web package (dist folder contents of VueJs/Angular/React App).
As shown in the screenshot, I've created 2 folders and copied dist contents after building Vuejs application.

[image: wwwroot folder structure]

If I copy dist contents directly to the wwwroot folder for one App and navigate to **localhost:5000/** then the app is being loaded properly.
But with multiple folders and when I navigate to **localhost:5000/page1/index.html** then the browser console shows the following error

> Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)

This is because the js and CSS folders are not loaded in the browser.

[image: Brower sources screenshot]

Below is my code in Startup.cs file.

```
app.UseStaticFiles();
app.UseFileServer(new FileServerOptions
{
   EnableDirectoryBrowsing = true,
});
```

Can someone help me solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While you could get 404 responses for each individual image, css, or javascript resource, the html file itself should **NOT** produce that result. Instead, you should see the page as it would render without those resources, each of which will show it's own 404 in your browser developer tools, but only *after* successfully loading the html.

There are several ways to fix the additional missing resources. Here are two:

1. Use relative references (`img/SomeImage.png` instead of `/img/SomeImage.png` or the full URL)
2. Use the `base` tag to reset the root to the current location (`<base  href="//localhost:5000/Page1/">`). This belongs in the `head` for the html.

Comment: We can remove the extra slash by setting - publicPath: "", - in vue.config.js